# How to open files from terminal in desired pattern (tabs, vertical and horizontal splits on desired files)

Tags: neovim, command-line, split, multiple-files

So, I wrote next bash script:

```sh
#!/bin/bash

if [ "$#" -gt 1 ]; then
    path=$1
else
    path=$(cat subject.txt | tr -d '\n')
fi

nvim -p 1 "setup/$path/body.tex" -p 1 preamble/preamble.tex -p 1 -O 1 homework.tex -o 1 setup.tex variables/variables.tex
```

By the

```sh
nvim -p 1 "setup/$path/body.tex" -p 1 preamble/preamble.tex -p 1 -O 1 homework.tex -o 1 setup.tex variables/variables.tex
```

I mean:

> `-p 1` - create one tab and open `"setup/$path/body.tex"` int it (so that tab is taken), then do `-p 1` - open `preamble/preamble.tex` in second tab so second tab is also taken, then do `-p 1 -O 1` - create third tab and vertically divide it into two windows, in first vertical window we should open `homework.tex` then divide second window horizontally and in first half of second vertical window we should open `setup.tex` and in the second half of second vertical window we should open `variables/variables.tex`.

So, as a result of these simple operations we should have the next:

[image]

But, instead I get:

[image]

How to open files from terminal in desired pattern?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can run custom script with `-S` option. Using bash heredoc, you can pass a fd as file to vim. You can also interpolate with bash variables.

```bash
fname=someFilePath

vim -S /proc/self/fd/9 9<<VIMS
vsp fileOnSplit
sp $fname
tabe fileOnTab1
tabe fileOnTab2
tabr
VIMS
```

Comment: The /proc/ but shouldn’t be necessary, I think, and isn’t OS portable. I’ll suggest a few other versions when I get to my computer

Answer (score 0):

Options for custom layout:

- If the commands are short, using `-c` will do, like `vim -c 'edit foo' -c 'split bar'`
- Otherwise, use a session file with `-S`. This can be created in several ways:

  - with `:mksession`
  - by typing commands into a file
  - with herefiles in supported shells:

    ```sh
    vim -S <(cat <<EOF
    edit foo
    split bar
    EOF
    )
    ```

    Notably, this version of a herefile or heredoc does not rely on the `/proc` filesystem.