# Writing a bash script to startup Vim in a particular configuration for a project

Tags: vimrc, bash, startup

I want to write a bash script that starts up a Vim session using a specific configuration.

For instance consider a C project with the following structure

```
project_dir
 - src
   - file1.c
   - file2.c
   - Makefile
 - include
   - file1.h
   - file2.h
   - Makefile
 - tests
   - test_file1.c
   - test_file2.c
   - Makefile
 - Makefile
```

I can already write something like

```
vim project_dir/src/*.c project_dir/include/*.h project_dir/tests/*.c project_dir/Makefile
```

to open all the files as buffers.

However apart from this single file per window tab, I would like to open couple more tabs like one tab which displays related src and header files as vertical splits and another tab that opens certain test source code and relevant src files as vertical splits.

I do not however even know how to accomplish the simple task of say calling Vim from terminal so that there would be two tabs on startup. I tried using `vim -c` as per some of the threads I saw here but never managed to get any command executed.

I guess project specific vimrc files could be one way (I think can figure out how to do this from the vimrc) but would prefer to try to do it as terminal commands in a bash script if possible.

For using -c I tried the following:

```
src_path="/home/avicenna/local_packages/test/src"
inc_path="/home/avicenna/local_packages/test/include"
tests_path="/home/avicenna/local_packages/test/tests"

src_files=("$src_path"/*.c)
header_files=("$inc_path"/*.h)
test_files=("$tests_path"/*.c)

c1=''"'"':tabnew '"${src_files[0]}"''"'"''
vim_args="${src_files[@]} ${header_files[@]} -c"
vim_args="${vim_args} ${c1}"

vim "${vim_args}"

echo "vim ${vim_args}"
```

I died a little when trying to include the single quotes correctly maybe there is a better way. However the strange thing is although when I call this script the second tab does not open, if I just copy paste the echoed command and run it directly from the shell it works fine. Not sure what I am missing here? The echoed command is

```
vim /home/avicenna/local_packages/test/src/file1.c /home/avicenna/local_packages/test/src/file2.c /home/avicenna/local_packages/test/include/file1.h /home/avicenna/local_packages/test/include/file2.h -c ':tabnew /home/avicenna/local_packages/test/src/file1.c'
```

Note that if I replace c1 above by

```
c1="\":tabnew "${src_files[0]}"\""
```

I still have the same problem. Running the bash script does not open the tab but copy pasting and executing the command in terminal does.

Update: Changing

```
vim "${vim_args}"
```

to

```
eval "vim ${vim_args}"
```

did the trick somehow, I have no idea why.

Comment: "I tried using vim -c as per some of the threads I saw here but never managed to get any command executed." Let's see what you tried.

Comment: Welcome to vi SE. You may want to take a look at `:help :mksession`. You should be able to put everything in a session file. It would be a middle way between bash script and a project-specific vimrc.

Comment: @romainl I now figured out I was not using it correctly. vim1 file1.txt -c ":tabnew" seems to work. But it seems the session idea suggested by Friedrich seems like a more canonical way to do what I want. Thanks

Comment: for people interested: I also found this which is using -c argument indeed to do it https://stackoverflow.com/questions/73876317/vim-custom-tab-and-vertical-split-organization-on-open

Comment: Once you figure out how to solve your problem, please post an answer so others can benefit from it. Thank you.

Comment: See https://vi.stackexchange.com/a/41731

Comment: @Friedrich I could only come up with a partial solution which I added to the answer above. Would appreciate any help with regards to fixing it.

Comment: @romainl strangely enough when I call -c from bash it does not seem to achieve the desired effect.

Comment: You forgot to include the output of `echo "vim ${vim_args}"`.

Comment: @romainl I added the output to the message above and double checked that if I copy paste that into terminal vim opens with the tab as expected. Is this me not handling single quotes correctly in bash?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

## Sessions

A session is a file of vimscript commands, which you can create manually
for full control or with `:mksession` to preserve an existing layout (with
caveats). I'm particularly fond of https://github.com/tpope/vim-obsession with
sessions.

Start a session with `vim -S <session>`; the default is `Session.vim` and can be
launched with `vim -S`.

## Shell

You tried this, but the problem is that `"${vim_args}"` doesn't word-split the
expansion of the `vim_args` variable. You could unquote it, but then it's also
subject to globbing and files with spaces would not be supported. It seemed like
you were a bit confused on how shell words and quoting worked. Further, `echo` is a poor debug tool because of how it works (even `print '%s\n'` isn't enough here, but might have helped you spot the problem). You can always use `declare -p` in Bash to check the value of a variable.

With a modern Bash that supports arrays, I would write like this. Don't use a literal string of arguments if you don't need to; it's unnecessarily complicated and brittle. Always ShellCheck.

```
#! /bin/bash

package=~/local_packages/test
src_path=$package/src
inc_path=$package/include
tests_path=$package/tests

src_files=("$src_path"/*.c)
header_files=("$inc_path"/*.h)
# unused: perhaps you meant to include it?
test_files=("$tests_path"/*.c)

args=(
  "${src_files[@]}"
  "${header_files[@]}"
  -c ":tabnew ${src_files[0]}"
)

# use exec to throw away the intermediate shell process; don't do this if you
have commands after `vim` in the script
exec vim "${args[@]}"
```

Answer (score 1):

In terms of achieving it from bash (see Friedrich's comment above for alternate method) I was able to come up with the following code which works

```
src_path="src"
inc_path="include"
tests_path="tests"

src_files=("$src_path"/*.c)
header_files=("$inc_path"/*.h)
test_files=("$tests_path"/*.c)

c1="\":tabnew "${src_files[0]}" | :vs "${header_files[0]}"\""
c2="\":tabnew "${test_files[0]}" | :vs "${header_files[0]}"\""

vim_args="${src_files[*]} ${header_files[*]} -c ${c1} -c ${c2}"

eval "vim ${vim_args}"
```

Funny enough eval was necessary only calling `vim ${vim_args}` does not work!

Comment: You're never declaring `test_files`.

Comment: added them now thanks. Also it would seem based on ShellCheck that when you want to include a list in a string * is a better practice than @ so changed that too